# How to take a list of strings and multiply each by 2 in python?

Tags: python, list, sum

I know this is vague so I'm going to try and explain it as best as I can here. . I've tried working on the multiplying by 2 problem for about 3 hours now and I can't figure anything out. I'm assuming I must make a new variable and use the int function but I've tried a bunch of different combinations of things and nothing works. I'm sorry if this makes absolutely no sense. I'm very new to coding, so please let me know if I need to explain more or if there's a much simpler way to do this.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map `map(lambda x: str(2*int(x)), ["2", "4", "7"])`

Answer (score 1):

```
a=  ["2", "4", "7"]
a_2 =  [2*int(i) for i in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to an integer, you can use `int(a)`.

To create a list based on elements from some other list, you can use list comprehension, for example `[x * 2 for x in other_list]`.

If you put this together, you get `[int(a)*2 for a in ["2", "4", "7"]]`.

Comment: Thank you jurez!

Answer (score 1):

I think a for loop would be best for this.
The code will go through each element in the list, then change its value by multiplying it by 2.

Also based on your description i assume you just were assigning your values as string because of the brackets around the numbers

```
integers = [1,2,7,8]
for x in range(len(integers)):
         newx = integers[x] * 2
         integers[x] = newx
print(integers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's built-in function `map`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

`list(map(lambda x: str(2*int(x)), ["2", "4", "7"]))`

This creates the list `["4", "8", "14"]`

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas!